# Remove/Update row in database with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

On the site users have option to add other users as a friend. Now I want to make option to delete some user from the friend list. The problem is that I don't know how exactly to do it with jquery part.

This is the button for remove

```
<a href="#" class="delete" id="'.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-times pull-right"></i></a>
```

Then this is the jquery part

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.delete').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('media-heading');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'misc/friendRemove.php', 
        data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + $(this).attr('id'),
        beforeSend: function() {
            parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
        },
        success: function() {
            parent.fadeOut(300,function() {
                parent.remove();
            });
        }
    });         
});

$('.delete').confirm({
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete?",
    title: "Confirmation required",

    confirmButton: "Yes",
    cancelButton: "No",
    post: true,
    confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
    cancelButtonClass: "btn-default",
    dialogClass: "modal-dialog modal-lg"
});     
});
```

and the `friendRemove.php`

```
    if(isset($_POST['id']) {  

    $friend_id = $_POST['id'];

            $value = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE user_friends SET isDeleted = `1` and isActive = `0` WHERE friend_id= ?');
            $value->bindParam(1, $friend_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);               
            $value->execute();
            $result = $value->fetch();    

}
```

Where I'm wrong?

On Console in the Chrome I get this error so far

```
friendRemove.php?ajax=1&delete=37 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

UPDATE: I'm very new into jquery and I used this from one tutorial..

UPDATE: this is the table if it's matter but I can't update it even from sql query in the phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_friends` (
  `friend_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `friendsSince` datetime NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`friend_id`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

UPDATE: Query should be like this

```
UPDATE user_friends SET isDeleted = 1, isActive = 0 WHERE friend_id = ?
```

instead of this

```
UPDATE user_friends SET isDeleted = 1 AND isActive = 0 WHERE friend_id = ?
```

Comment: Do you have the connection it the php file?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't copied here.. It's in another file and it is included here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax type is

```
 type: 'get',
```

So instead of `POST` you have to use GET and closing issue of `isset` function

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {  // here closing issue also

    $friend_id = $_GET['id'];
```

Remove `backtick` from value of `isDeleted and isActive`

```
 $value = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE user_friends SET isDeleted = 1 and isActive = 0 WHERE friend_id= ?');
```

SO you full php code would be

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {

    $friend_id = $_GET['delete'];
    $value = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE user_friends SET isDeleted = 1 and isActive = 0 WHERE friend_id= ?');
    $value->bindParam(1, $friend_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $value->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank's for this mistakes. I fixed them but still doesn't update fields in database. Also no errors in Console of the browser.

Comment: CHeck you update query and try to run in phpmyadmin. also remove `$result = $value->fetch();` because update does not fatch data from database

Comment: It is very strange. For example this query: `UPDATE user_friends SET isDeleted = 1 and isActive = 0 WHERE friend_id= 37` is succeeded but that row in the table doesn't change values of the `isDeleted` and `isActive`

Comment: Both columns are with default values and `tinyint(1)`

Comment: Same. No errors at all the exact same query I run in phpmyadmin and is succeeded but still doesn't change values of the rows. I can't get it why..

Comment: `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['delete']` at the same time?

Comment: It is not. Still I have `isDeleted=0` and `isActive=1`

Comment: Found the problem - `UPDATE user_friends SET isDeleted = 1, isActive = 0 WHERE friend_id = ?` without `AND` in the query

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making a GET request, if you are looking for the `id` variable in the URL request, you have to explicitly set it ... right now you're looking for `$_POST['id']`, but it looks like you should be looking for `$_GET['delete']` from how you've set the URL parameters via the AJAX request.

Comment: What do you find on server side when you see what the value of `$_GET['delete']` is?  Also is your SQL query itself working?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ´ from the code.

```
$value = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE user_friends SET isDeleted = `1` and isActive = `0` WHERE friend_id= ?'
```

Modified line:

```
$value = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE user_friends SET isDeleted = 1 and isActive = 0 WHERE friend_id= ?'
```